# Mockito: Stubbing Methods That Return Type With Bounded Wild-Cards

Tags: java, unit-testing, generics, mockito, bounded-wildcard

Consider this code:

```java
public class DummyClass {
    public List<? extends Number> dummyMethod() {
        return new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }
}
```

```java
public class DummyClassTest {
    public void testMockitoWithGenerics() {
        DummyClass dummyClass = Mockito.mock(DummyClass.class);
        List<? extends Number> someList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Mockito.when(dummyClass.dummyMethod()).thenReturn(someList); //Compiler complains about this
    }
}
```

The compiler complains about the line that's trying to stub the behavior for `dummyMethod()`. Any pointers on how one goes about stubbing methods that return a type with bounded wild-cards?

Comment: Can you update your code snippet to show the generic types?

Comment: Done. I had to remove pre and code tags, they were stripping-off <? extends Number> from the type declaration.

Answer (score 238, accepted):

You can also use the non-type safe method [doReturn](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.13.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doReturn-java.lang.Object-) for this purpose,

```
@Test
public void testMockitoWithGenerics()
{
    DummyClass dummyClass = Mockito.mock(DummyClass.class);
    List<? extends Number> someList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Mockito.doReturn(someList).when(dummyClass).dummyMethod();

    Assert.assertEquals(someList, dummyClass.dummyMethod());
}
```

as [discussed](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mockito/ljVV1GiJe9Y/9OdFbxvjQNcJ) on Mockito's google group.

While this is simpler than `thenAnswer`, again note that it is not type safe.  If you're concerned about type safety, millhouse's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7655709/277307) is correct.

#### Additional Details

To be clear, here's the observed compiler error,

> `The method thenReturn(List<capture#1-of ? extends Number>) in the type OngoingStubbing<List<capture#1-of ? extends Number>> is not applicable for the arguments (List<capture#2-of ? extends Number>)`

I believe the compiler has assigned the first wildcard type during the `when` call and then cannot confirm that the second wildcard type in the `thenReturn` call is the same.

It looks like `thenAnswer` doesn't run into this issue because it accepts a wildcard type while `thenReturn` takes a non-wildcard type, which must be captured.  From Mockito's [OngoingStubbing](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.13.0/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html),

```
OngoingStubbing<T> thenAnswer(Answer<?> answer);
OngoingStubbing<T> thenReturn(T value);
```

Comment: this partially help me as well... but what happens if the list you expect to return is not empty?

Comment: instead of having an empty list you can you can also do :
    List<Number> someList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    someList.add(aNumber);

Comment: This answer around the same question is quite nice : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19119230/4214921

Answer (score 39):

I'm assuming you want to be able to load up `someList` with some known values; here's an approach that uses `Answer<T>` together with a templated helper method to keep everything type-safe:

```
@Test
public void testMockitoWithGenericsUsingAnswer()
{
    DummyClass dummyClass =  Mockito.mock(DummyClass.class);

    Answer<List<Integer>> answer = setupDummyListAnswer(77, 88, 99);
    Mockito.when(dummyClass.dummyMethod()).thenAnswer(answer);

    ...
}

private <N extends Number> Answer<List<N>> setupDummyListAnswer(N... values) {
    final List<N> someList = new ArrayList<N>();

    someList.addAll(Arrays.asList(values));

    Answer<List<N>> answer = new Answer<List<N>>() {
        public List<N> answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            return someList;
        }   
    };
    return answer;
}
```

Answer (score 22):

I hit the same thing yesterday. Both answers from @nondescript1 and @millhouse helped me to figure out a workaround. I've pretty much used the same code as @millhouse, except that I made it slightly more generic, because my error wasn't caused by a `java.util.List`, but the `com.google.common.base.Optional`. My little helper method therefore allows for any type `T` and not just `List<T>`:

```
public static <T> Answer<T> createAnswer(final T value) {
    Answer<T> dummy = new Answer<T>() {
        @Override
        public T answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            return value;
        }
    };
    return dummy;
}
```

With this helper method you could write:

```
Mockito.when(dummyClass.dummyMethod()).thenAnswer(createAnswer(someList));
```

This compiles just fine and does the same thing as the `thenReturn(...)` method.

Does someone know if the error that the Java compiler emits is a compiler bug or if the code is really incorrect?

Comment: This seems straightforward, simple and, as near as I can tell, correct.  I'm not sure why Mockito does not provide something similar to this.......unless it does?

Comment: In Java 8 it can be shortened: `Mockito.when(dummyClass.dummyMethod()).thenAnswer(x -> someList)`, so no need for the utility method

Comment: @fikovnik What a great discovery "thenAnswer" !

Comment: You can write it quite elegantly like this:     public static <T> Answer<T> createAnswer(final T value) {
        return (invocation) -> value;
    }

Answer (score 16):

I'm turning [*fikovnik*'s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366237/mockito-stubbing-methods-that-return-type-with-bounded-wild-cards/10688480#comment57015583_17867293) into an answer here to give it more visibility as I think it's the most elegant solution using Java 8+.

The [Mockito documentation](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.28.2/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doReturn) recommends using `doReturn()` (as suggested in the accepted answer) only as a last resort.

Instead, to circumevent the compiler error described in the question, the recommended Mockito `when()` approach can be used with `thenAnswer()` and a lambda (instead of a helper method):

```
Mockito.when(mockedClass.mockedMethod()).thenAnswer(x -> resultList)
```

Comment: though it doesn't give any compile time errors, the returned list is empty even when we are passing a list with entries.

Answer (score 1):

Although the utility method proposed by Marek Radonsky works, there is also an other option which doesn't even require the (IMHO strange looking) lambda expression fikovnik suggested:

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15944985/6418426) to a similar question shows, you can also use the following:

```
BDDMockito.willReturn(someList).given(dummyClass).dummyMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

## Remove `? extends`  from your DummyClass return type.

**Noncompliant Code Example:**

> --List<? extends Number> dummyMethod() {...}--

**Compliant Solution**

```
List<Number> dummyMethod() {
  
  List<Integer> result = ...
  return List.copyOf(result);
}
```

NOTE: `List.copyOf()` implementation is performant **if** your collection is created with List.of, Stream.toList, etc., effectively doing a cast rather than a real copy. See its source code: [src 1](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/List.java#L1061), **[src 2](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ImmutableCollections.java#L90)**.

**JUSTIFICATION:** Using a wildcard like `<? extends Number>` in the return type is a critical "Code Smell". Because would force your client code to struggle with wildcard-type declarations, as in your example with Mockito.

### REFERENCEs:

- Joshua Bloch "[Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134685997)" Item 31:

> ***Do not use** <> **wildcard types as return types**, because it would force client code to use wildcards. Properly used, wildcards are nearly invisible to the user of a class. **If the user of a class has to think about wildcard types, there is probably something wrong with its API.***

- Sonar code quality [Rule java:S1452](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1452/)

  - category: **Code smell**; severity: **Critical**

> *It is highly recommended **not** to use wildcard types as return types. Because the type inference rules are fairly complex it is unlikely the user of that API will know how to use it correctly.*

> *...covariance is ineffective for the return type of a method since it is not an input position. Making it contravariant also has no effect since it is the receiver of the return value which must be contravariant (use-site variance in Java). Consequently, **a return type containing wildcards is generally a mistake.***