# mock method with generic and extends in return type

Tags: java, generics, mockito

Is it possible to mock (with mockito) method with signature `Set<? extends Car> getCars()` without supress warnings? i tried:

```
XXX cars = xxx;
when(owner.getCars()).thenReturn(cars);
```

but no matter how i declare `cars` i alway get a compilation error.
e.g when i declare like this

```
Set<? extends Car> cars = xxx
```

i get the standard generic/mockito compilation error

```
The method thenReturn(Set<capture#1-of ? extends Car>) in the type OngoingStubbing<Set<capture#1-of ? extends Car>> is not applicable for the arguments (Set<capture#2-of ? extends Car>)
```

Comment: what compilation error are you getting, can you copy/paste?

Comment: Warning suppression, compilation failure, and exceptions are all different things... I think you might be confusing them here.

Comment: i tried to explain everything precisely. so once more to be clear. i want my code compile. also i'd like that code has no warnings and no `@SupressWarning`. i've never mentioned anything about exceptions. hope that helps

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366237/mockito-stubbing-methods-that-return-type-with-bounded-wild-cards

Comment: I agree it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366237/mockito-stubbing-methods-that-return-type-with-bounded-wild-cards except that one's actually newer, so isn't it the duplicate.  But it has more answers.  And arguable a clearer title.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use the doReturn-when alternate stubbing syntax.

System under test:

```
public class MyClass {
  Set<? extends Number> getSet() {
    return new HashSet<Integer>();
  }
}
```

and the test case:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.junit.Test;

public class TestMyClass {
  @Test
  public void testGetSet() {
    final MyClass mockInstance = mock(MyClass.class);

    final Set<Integer> resultSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
    resultSet.add(1);
    resultSet.add(2);
    resultSet.add(3);

    doReturn(resultSet).when(mockInstance).getSet();

    System.out.println(mockInstance.getSet());
  }
}
```

No errors or warning suppression needed

Comment: ugly but works. I hate this syntax for two reasons. readability and the fact we are completely resign from using generics at all. Is it really impossible to do it with generics?

Comment: I understand your dislike of the syntax, I prefer the when-then syntax as well.  I don't understand what you mean about it being impossible to do it with generics though.

Comment: i'm talking about the parameter of doReturn. it's object. it is not bound in any way to the type that should be returned. there is no compilation-time type checking. however if i get no better answer i'll take this one, because as i said - it works

Comment: Indeed.  Like the documentation says: "Beware that when(Object) is always recommended for stubbing because it is argument type-safe and more readable (especially when stubbing consecutive calls)."  But since the when() method returns a generisized OngoingStubbing<T> where T is the type of the method supplied to when(), and then requires a thenReturn(T) call...I wouldn't think there is any way to avoid this compiler error, it's supposed to happen.  Could you get rid of the wildcard in the method you're stubbing?  Making it into a class parameter instead?

Comment: See the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19119230/193606 for a typesafe alternative

Answer (score 0):

## Remove `? extends` from your return type.

Using a wildcard like `<? extends Car>` in the return type is a critical "Code Smell". Because would force your client code to struggle with wildcard-type declarations, as in your example with Mockito.

**Noncompliant Code Example:**

> --Set<? extends Car> getCars() {...}--

**Compliant Solution**

```
Set<Car> getCars() {
  
  Set<? extends Car> result = ...
  return Set.copyOf(result);
}
```

NOTE: Set`.copyOf()` implementation is performant, effectively doing a cast rather than a real copy if your collection is created with Set.of, Stream.toList, etc. See its [source code](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Set.java#L725).

### REFERENCEs:

- Joshua Bloch "[Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134685997)" Item 31:

> ***Do not use** <> **wildcard types as return types**, because it would force client code to use wildcards. Properly used, wildcards are nearly invisible to the user of a class. **If the user of a class has to think about wildcard types, there is probably something wrong with its API.***

- Sonar code quality [Rule java:S1452](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1452/)

  - category: **Code smell**; severity: **Critical**

> *It is highly recommended **not** to use wildcard types as return types. Because the type inference rules are fairly complex it is unlikely the user of that API will know how to use it correctly.*

> *...covariance is ineffective for the return type of a method since it is not an input position. Making it contravariant also has no effect since it is the receiver of the return value which must be contravariant (use-site variance in Java). Consequently, **a return type containing wildcards is generally a mistake.***