# How to handle different return type of a method in then Return?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I have a method that returns `ResponseEntity<?>`. I want to handle that return in the `Mockito.when().thenReturn();`
I get the following error.

```
the method thenreturn(responseentity<capture#6-of ?>) in the type ongoingstubbing<responseentity<capture#6-of ?>> is not applicable for the arguments (responseentity<capture#7-of ?>)
```

Here is my code:

```
@Mock
EmisionesApi emisionesApi;

@InjectMocks
EmisionesControllerImpl emisionesControllerImpl = new EmisionesControllerImpl();

@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() {

}

@Test
public void testBuscarModalidades() throws Exception {
    try {
        final String compania = "11";
        final String producto = "10";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        List<ProductoComercial> productoComercials = new ArrayList<ProductoComercial>();
        ProductoComercial pc = new ProductoComercial();
        productoComercials.add(pc);
        ResponseEntity<List<ProductoComercial>> salida = new ResponseEntity<List<ProductoComercial>>(productoComercials, HttpStatus.OK);

        ProductosComercialesDto productosComercialesDto = new ProductosComercialesDto();
        String jsonBody = mapper.writeValueAsString(productosComercialesDto);

        String urlBackend = PowerMockito.mock(String.class);
        Whitebox.setInternalState(emisionesControllerImpl, "urlBackend", urlBackend);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = new ResponseEntity<String>(jsonBody, HttpStatus.OK);

        RestTemplateSSO rt = PowerMockito.mock(RestTemplateSSO.class);
        Mockito.doNothing().when(rt).setErrorHandler(Mockito.any(ResponseErrorHandler.class));
        Whitebox.setInternalState(emisionesControllerImpl, "rt", rt);
        Mockito.when(rt.exchange(Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.any(HttpMethod.class), Matchers.<HttpEntity<?>> any(), Matchers.<Class<String>> any())).thenReturn(response);

        Mockito.doReturn(salida).when(emisionesApi).getModalidades(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString());
        Mockito.when(emisionesApi.getModalidades(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(salida);

        ResponseEntity<List<ProductoComercial>> sal = (ResponseEntity<List<ProductoComercial>>) emisionesControllerImpl.getModalidades(compania, producto);
        Assert.assertTrue(sal.getBody().size() == 1);
        Assert.assertTrue(sal.getStatusCode() == salida.getStatusCode());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The method that I want to test is:

`public ResponseEntity<?> getModalidades`
the return is each time different from this method based on the statusCode.

I tried using doReturn but it's ignored. I don't know why.

Comment: **Offtopic**: "_`String urlBackend = PowerMockito.mock(String.class);`_". Why would you ever want  to do that?! Unless you have a very mega giga ultra special corner case, there's no need to mock simple objects/values. Just use an actual `String`, `Integer`, `List`, "_`Person`_", etc, so simply do `String urlBackend = "whatever";` (a few more [suggestions](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/How-to-write-good-tests) to consider)

Comment: **Ontopic**: you should be able to use [`doReturn(response).when(rt).exchange(...).`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.25.1/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doReturn-java.lang.Object-) to bypass the issue. (possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15942880/mocking-a-method-that-return-generics-with-wildcard-using-mockito)

Comment: @Morfic I bring the urlBackend from pom.xml based on maven profile. That is why I had to mock that String. I managed to fix it by not specifying the type of salida Response entity. I don't know if what I did is reasonable but it works now. I just started working with Mockito.

Comment: 1) That works too, you just don't get the benefits of type safety. However since your method returns multiple things, it may be an indication that your class may be doing more stuff than it should, so you may want to consider refactoring it to make things clearer... 2) You can get the string from wherever you need, I don't see any reason to mock the `String` class. Just inject any literal value you want...