# Can't return Class Object with Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm trying to write a unit test, and to do that I'm writing a when statement for a Mockito mock, but I can't seem to get eclipse to recognize that my return value is valid.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
Class<?> userClass = User.class;
when(methodParameter.getParameterType()).thenReturn(userClass);
```

The return type of `.getParameterType()` is `Class<?>`, so I don't understand why eclipse says, `The method thenReturn(Class<capture#1-of ?>) in the type OngoingStubbing<Class<capture#1-of ?>> is not applicable for the arguments (Class<capture#2-of ?>)`. It offers to cast my userClass, but that just makes some garbled stuff eclipse says it needs to cast again (and can't cast).

Is this just an issue with Eclipse, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Also, a slightly more terse way to get around this is to use the do syntax instead of when.

```
doReturn(User.class).when(methodParameter).getParameterType();
```

Comment: This is the cleanest solution.

Comment: Awesome ... yup, cleanest solution. Many Thanks.

Comment: This saved my day, thanks!

Comment: Returned here after years probably (since I see I already upvoted) and it saved me yet again :D I guess I should save what I learn in memory better. Thanks !

Answer (score 31):

```
Class<?> userClass = User.class;
OngoingStubbing<Class<?>> ongoingStubbing = Mockito.when(methodParameter.getParameterType());
ongoingStubbing.thenReturn(userClass);
```

The `OngoingStubbing<Class<?>>` returned by `Mockito.when` is not the same type as `ongoingStubbing` because each '?' wildcard could be bound to a different type.

To make the types match, you need to specify the type parameter explicitly:

```
Class<?> userClass = User.class;
Mockito.<Class<?>>when(methodParameter.getParameterType()).thenReturn(userClass);
```

Comment: The part: `Mockito.<Class<?>>when` was the key. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: In my opinion using explicit typing is a more elegant solution than the currently voted 'correct' answer

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure why you're getting this error.  It must have something special to do with returning `Class<?>`.  Your code compiles fine if you return `Class`.  This is a simulation of what you're doing and this test passes.  I think this will work for you, too:

```
package com.sandbox;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock;
import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

import static junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals;

public class SandboxTest {

    @Test
    public void testQuestionInput() {
        SandboxTest methodParameter = mock(SandboxTest.class);
        final Class<?> userClass = String.class;
        when(methodParameter.getParameterType()).thenAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
                return userClass;
            }
        });

        assertEquals(String.class, methodParameter.getParameterType());
    }

    public Class<?> getParameterType() {
        return null;
    }


}
```

Comment: Yes, it seems like it must be an issue with eclipse or mockito. I was able to implement your suggestion, and that got around the issue, so thanks!

Comment: @CorayThan It's not Eclipse.  This doesn't compile in Intellij, either.

Comment: Same in Intellij Idea

Comment: The original poster doesn't mention what JDK he used, but I believe this is due to the stronger type checking in Java 8, and thus wouldn't be due to eclipse or Intellij. I've run into this issue quite a bit upgrading working unit tests (albeit full of @SuppressWarnings for raw types) from Java 7 to Java 8. More detail here: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/compiler-dev/2013-November/008038.html

Comment: Thanks for that. it's even more nice with todays lambdas: when(methodParameter.getParameterType()).thenAnswer(
                (Answer<Object>) invocationOnMock -> String.class);

Answer (score 6):

You can simply remove  from Class))

```
Class userClass = User.class;
when(methodParameter.getParameterType()).thenReturn(userClass);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the code examples here a little confusing with the use of methodParameter.getParameterType() first used in the accepted answer's SandBoxTest. After I did a little more digging I found [another thread pertaining to this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554955/mock-method-with-generic-and-extends-in-return-type) that provided a better example. This example made it clear the Mockito call I was in need of was doReturn(myExpectedClass).when(myMock).callsMyMethod(withAnyParams). Using that  form allows me to mock a return of Class. Hopefully this note will help someone searching on a similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Two more solutions:

Here we trade the compilation error for an Unchecked assignment warning:

```java
Class<?> userClass = User.class;
when(methodParameter.getParameterType()).thenReturn((Class)userClass);
```

A more concise solution without warnings would be

```java
Class<?> userClass = User.class;
when(methodParameter.getParameterType()).thenAnswer(__ -> userClass);
```