# Mockito: Mocking AnnotationType

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I would like to mock the method annotationType() which returns `Class<? extends Annotation>`.

But the following line gives me a compilation error.

```
when(annotation.annotationType()).thenReturn(notNullClass.getClass());
```

I am using java 1.7.0_45. I am receiving compilation error that I need to pass `Class<? extends Annotation>` as parameter.

Any idea what should I put as argument of `thenReturn` in order to compile?

Comment: What compilation error are you receiving? And what version of java are you running?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't return Class Object with Mockito](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890133/cant-return-class-object-with-mockito)

Comment: this solved my issue: Mockito.doReturn(NotNull.class).when(NotNullAnnotation).annotationType();

Answer (score 2):

`annotation.annotationType()` returns `Class<? extends Annotation>`.

**So you have to return a Class object of some annotation type**.

Comment: Tnx for the prompt response, however could you make any example?

Comment: `notNullClass.getClass()` feels like it returns `Class<Class>`, using only `notNullClass` should do the trick

Comment: @Brice not really, still says "cannot resolve method(javax.validation.constraints.NotNull)"