# Mocking a method that returns an Iterator with Captured Generics

Tags: java, generics, mockito

I'm using a third party library which has a method of the form:

```
public interface ThirdPartyMessageThing<T> {
    Iterator<? extends MessageEntry<T>> getMessages(){}
}
```

I'm trying to mock the call to getMessages() to return a mocked Iterator so I can control the behaviour of `hasNext()` and `next()` using Mockito.

I have a mocked `ThirdPartyMessageThing<String>` object called `thirdPartyMessageThing`.

If I try to mock the iterator like so:

```
Iterator<MessageEntry<String>> mockedIterator = Mockito.mock(Iterator.class);
```

The mock seems to be okay until I try to return it as a mock from a call to `when()` in:

```
when(thirdPartyMessageThing.getMessages()).thenReturn(mockedIterator);
```

The compiler doesn't like this saying that it can't resolve the method.

I get the same behaviour if I use my IDE's autocomplete to generate a local variable from a call to the method I'm trying to mock:

```
Iterator<? extends MessageEntry<String>> mockedIterator =
                                thirdPartyMessageThing.getMessages();
```

And try to use that as the parameter to `thenReturn()`.
However if I just just put a `mock(Iterator.class)` into `thenReturn()` as a parameter, the compiler doesn't complain, but I can't access the Iterator to override it's methods.

How can I mock this Iterator in such a way that I can use it as a mock and override it's methods?

Answer (score 1):

I'm marking this as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554955/mock-method-with-generic-and-extends-in-return-type#10557418) as I've found a way to get it working.

For reference sake what I ended up doing was constructing a dummy List<> and returning the iterator of that. This works if you use the `doReturn(returnValue).when(mockedObject).methodName()` syntax.

An alternative mechanism which I also found to work was casting the generic iterator to a plain iterator, this however raises warnings about unchecked exceptions.