# Mockito: cannot resolve method 'thenReturn(List<capture of ? extends X>)'

Tags: java, generics, mockito

**I don't understand why this code with Java generics fails to compile**. Given this class:

```
public static class X {
    public List<? extends X> getList() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

there's no way to mock the `getList` return value:

```
X x = mock(X.class);
// Error: Cannot resolve method 'thenReturn(List<T>)'
when(x.getList()).thenReturn(Collections.singletonList(new X()));
// Error: Cannot resolve method 'thenReturn(List<capture of ? extends X>)'
when(x.getList()).thenReturn((List<? extends X>) Collections.singletonList(new X()));
// Error: Cannot resolve method 'thenReturn(List<capture of ?>)'
when(x.getList()).thenReturn((List<?>) Collections.singletonList(new X()));
```

The only way of making it work with "when...then" seems to be stripping generics entirely, at the cost of a compiler warning:

```
when(x.getList()).thenReturn((List) Collections.singletonList(new X()));
```

Ultimately, only this works:

```
doReturn(Collections.singletonList(new X())).when(x.getList());
```

Comment: checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366237/mockito-stubbing-methods-that-return-type-with-bounded-wild-cards/7655709#7655709)?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56791051/838434) seems to be the most elegant answer:

```
when(x.getList()).thenAnswer(unused -> Collections.singletonList(new X()));
```

I still don't know what the problem is with the original statement, though.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
        when((List<X>)x.getList()).thenReturn(Collections.singletonList(new X()));
```