# How do I mock method chains returning a Collection of interface implementations?

Tags: java, mockito

Suppose I need to mock a method chain that returns a `Collection` of some interface implementations:

```java
import lombok.Getter;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.List;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class MockingTest {
    @Test
    void test() {
        List<SomeOtherInterfaceImplementation> implementations = List.of(new SomeOtherInterfaceImplementation());

        SomeClass someClassMock = mock(SomeClass.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
        when(someClassMock.getSomeDependency().getSomeOtherInterfaceImplementations()).thenReturn(implementations);
    }
    
    @Getter
    private static class SomeClass {
        SomeInterface someDependency;
    }
    
    private interface SomeInterface {
        List<? extends SomeOtherInterface> getSomeOtherInterfaceImplementations();
    }
    
    private interface SomeOtherInterface {}
    
    private static class SomeOtherInterfaceImplementation implements SomeOtherInterface {}
}
```

Sadly, the code above doesn't compile because [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366237/mockito-stubbing-methods-that-return-type-with-bounded-wild-cards). If it wasn't a method chain but a single call, I could do this:

```java
doReturn(implementations).when(someClassMock).getSomeOtherInterfaceImplementations();
```

With chains, that trick won't work (though the code will compile):

```java
// doesn't work

doReturn(implementations).when(someClassMock).getSomeDependency().getSomeOtherInterfaceImplementations();
```

```java
// still doesn't work

doReturn(implementations).when(someClassMock.getSomeDependency().getSomeOtherInterfaceImplementations());
```

How am I supposed to mock such method chains in Mockito? Is creating an extra mock the only solution?

```java
    @Test
    void test() {
        List<SomeOtherInterface> implementations = List.of(new SomeOtherInterfaceImplementation());

        SomeInterface someInterfaceMock = mock(SomeInterface.class);
        doReturn(implementations).when(someInterfaceMock).getSomeOtherInterfaceImplementations();
        
        SomeClass someClassMock = mock(SomeClass.class);
        when(someClassMock.getSomeDependency()).thenReturn(someInterfaceMock);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Mock twice

```
SomeDependency mockDependency = mock(SomeDependency.class)

when(someClassMock.getSomeDependency()).thenReturn(mockDependency);

when(mockDependency.getSomeOtherInterfaceImplementations()).thenReturn(implementations);
```

Comment: That's what I suggested in my question. But are there other ways?

Comment: https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html. 
`Foo mock = mock(Foo.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);`
`when(mock.getBar().getName()).thenReturn("deep");`
`assertEquals("deep", mock.getBar().getName());`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

as per [Mockito](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS) documentation you can do something like that to chain stubs :

```
//this:
Foo mock = mock(Foo.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);    
when(mock.getBar().getName(), "deep");

//is equivalent of    
Foo foo = mock(Foo.class); 
Bar bar = mock(Bar.class); 

when(foo.getBar()).thenReturn(bar);
when(bar.getName()).thenReturn("deep");
```

To use generic stubs you can do:

```
when(mock.someMethod(anyString())).thenAnswer(
     new Answer() {
         public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
             Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
             Object mock = invocation.getMock();
             return "called with arguments: " + Arrays.toString(args);
         }
 });
```

Using your example:

```
@Test
    void test() {
        SomeClass someClassMock = mock(SomeClass.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
        when(someClassMock.getSomeDependency().getSomeOtherInterfaceImplementations()).thenAnswer(invocationOnMock -> List.of(new SomeOtherInterfaceImplementation(),new SomeOtherInterfaceImplementation()));
    }
```

However in my opinion it's a bad practice. Mock should not return mock. If yo need to do something like that, most probably you are having problems with your objects design or test scope.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it doesn't make the original code compile. Please check the MRE in the post

Comment: @Hepoha updated using your example

Comment: The key is `thenAnswer()` then because it uses a wildcard. It *is* a workaround, I used it once